# Connecting with ssh from OSX to VHM centos server

Tags: ssh, terminal, cpanel, ssh-keys

I have the following situation:

- VHM cpanel server (using centos)
- pc mac: OS X Mavericks

I'm trying to setup ssh connection from my pc to vhm cpanel server.
I've made the following steps:

**In OS X:**

I've generate a public/private key like this:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I've succesfully generated with a passphrase: 
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub

**IN VHM:**

SSH Password Authorization Tweak OFF
Manage root’s SSH Keys > Import key

[image]

I've paste my id_rsa.pub key in the Public Key box.
I authorised the key

[image]

**IN OS X Terminal:**

```
$ ssh 111.111.111.11
```

( where 111.111.111.11 is the server adresss)

enter password: xxxxxx

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I've also tried

```
$ ssh root@111.111.111.11
```

but same results

I'm doing something wrong ? 
These are correct steps to give ssh access ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your key on a .txt file and login using that command:

```
 ssh –i key.txt –l root <IP>
```